# Add row/column/grant totals in dynamic pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to add row/column/grant totals (how many customers each of seller serviced and how many sellers each of customer had interacted with) for a dynamic pivot table in SQL query.

Since there are unknown numbers of sellers (columns in pivot table) in the actual data, I have to use dynamic pivot. I tried to use GROUP BY ROLLUP() and GROUP BY CUBE() but had failed to find the right place to fit them in.  Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the sample data:

```
create table t
(
  Id INT NOT NULL,
  Customer  varchar(5),
  StartDay date,
  Seller varchar(10)
);

insert into t values 
(1,       'Bob',      '1/4/2019',            'Joe'),
(1,       'Bob',      '2/7/2021',              'Joe'),
(2,       'Kime',      '8/9/2018',             'Tedy'),
(2,       'Kime',      '1/11/2019',             'Tedy'),
(2,       'Kime',      '10/1/2020',             'Anny'),
(3,       'Kelly',      '10/1/2020',             'Angle'),
(4,       'Ben',      '7/8/2020',           'Anny');
```

Here is the query with dynamic pivot table I have:

```
DECLARE @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Seller) 
                    from t
                    group by Seller
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

 set @query = N'SELECT Customer,' + @cols + N' from        
  (select Customer, Seller
  from t
            ) x
            pivot 
            ( count(Seller)
                for Seller in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Below is my expected outcome:

```
Customer    Angle   Anny    Joe     Tedy   Total
Ben         0       1       0       0      1
Bob         0       0       2       0      2
Kelly       1       0       0       0      1 
Kime        0       1       0       2      3
Total       1       2       2       2      7 (Grand total)
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (I doubt the above code will run on both.)

Comment: Based on the syntax this is certainly SQL Server; please don't tag irrelevant and conflicting technologies.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a brute force approach ... `UNION ALL`

```
DECLARE @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Seller) 
                    from t
                    group by Seller
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

 set @query = N'
 Select * 
  From (
         Select Customer, Seller from t
         Union All
         Select ''Total'',Seller From t
         Union All 
         Select Customer,''Total'' From t
         Union All
         Select ''Total'',''Total'' From t
        ) x
 pivot  ( count(Seller) for Seller in (' + @cols + N',[Total]) ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thanks John! That's exact what I need.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` for this, which can be much easier than messing around with `UNION ALL`. You can also combine that with a manual pivot using `COUNT(CASE`

```sql
DECLARE
    @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX)  
,   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
 
SET @cols = (
    SELECT '
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Seller = ' + QUOTENAME(Seller, '''') + ' THEN 1 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Seller) + ','
    FROM t
    GROUP BY Seller
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
 ).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

SET @query = N'
SELECT
  ISNULL(Customer, ''Totals'') AS Customer,' + @cols + '
  COUNT(*) AS Totals
FROM t
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (Customer),
    ()
)
ORDER BY
  GROUPING(Customer);
';

PRINT @query;   -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/O7e3BeSO)

Answer (score 1):

John kinda beat me to it, but here's a bit more convoluted version that uses a few less UNIONs:

```sql
drop table #t
create table #t
(
  Id INT NOT NULL,
  Customer  varchar(5),
  StartDay date,
  Seller varchar(10)
);

insert into #t values 
(1,       'Bob',      '1/4/2019',            'Joe'),
(1,       'Bob',      '2/7/2021',              'Joe'),
(2,       'Kime',      '8/9/2018',             'Tedy'),
(2,       'Kime',      '1/11/2019',             'Tedy'),
(2,       'Kime',      '10/1/2020',             'Anny'),
(3,       'Kelly',      '10/1/2020',             'Angle'),
(4,       'Ben',      '7/8/2020',           'Anny');

DECLARE @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX)  
,   @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @cols2  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Seller) 
                    from #t
                    group by Seller
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
,   @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT '+' + QUOTENAME(Seller) 
                    from #t
                    group by Seller
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

 set @query = N'
    SELECT Customer,' + @cols + ',' + @cols2 + ' AS totals
    from        
    (
        SELECT  Customer, Seller, 0 AS sort
        FROM    #t
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  ''Totals'', Seller, -1 AS sort
        FROM    #t
    ) x
    pivot 
    ( count(Seller)
    for Seller in (' + @cols + N')
    ) p 
   order by sort DESC
            '
exec sp_executesql @query;
```

The difference is that i manually create Totals column by summarizing the other Pivots, as well as a bit more explicit sorting.

I also have to add that while this is doable in SQL, usually it's better to perform this sort of pivot in your application / reporting tool

Comment: Thanks Siggemannen! I ran your suggestion and found the duplicates outcome (e.g. Kime  0  0  0  1  1
Kime  0  0  0  1  1).   Do you have any ideas why it happens?

Comment: Oh, good catch! That's cause i selected too many columns for the pivot. Have fixed the answer. The pivot syntax often trips me up

Comment: Why not use `GROUPING SETS` or `ROLLUP`?

Comment: I tried, but it got way too many rows, so didn't spent time on it, and figured union might be a better idea

Comment: @Charlieface, I tried both GROUP BY ROLLUP() and GROUP BY CUBE() but cannot figure out the right way.  Do you any thoughts about how to use them in my case?  Thanks.  Always Wanted to learn some things new.

Comment: @siggemannen, do you mind explain a little more about the logic of your methodology and the roles of "0 AS sort" and "-1 AS sort" -- why use them?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's to get sorting of the "Totals" column at the bottom. I didn't want to sort by name, since there might be some seller called Zed

Comment: @Ben Like this `SELECT ...  from ( SELECT ISNULL(Customer, 'Total') AS Customer, Seller, GROUPING(Customer) AS sort FROM    #t GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (Seller, Customer), (Seller) ) ) AS x PIVOT ( ... ORDER BY sort`

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for your feedback.  I tried your way (it's a great way no doubt) as below but the outcome does not look right: set ...query = N'
    SELECT Customer,' + ...cols + ',' + ...cols2 + ' AS Totals
    from        
    (
 SELECT ISNULL(Customer,''Totals'') AS Customer, Seller, GROUPING(Customer) AS sort 

FROM    t 

GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (Seller, Customer), (Seller) )
  ) AS x 
  
    pivot 
    ( count(Seller)
    for Seller in (' + ...cols + N')
    ) p 
   order by sort'.  Can you please verify it?  It's a great chance for me to learn something great!