# Invalid column name 'Amount2' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I ran the following query but got the error of "Invalid column name 'Amount2'". I cannot figure out what's wrong.

Here is the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    ProductName VARCHAR(50),
    Region VARCHAR(50),
    Month2 VARCHAR(50),
    Amount2 DECIMAL(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO Sales VALUES 
       ('Product A', 'North', 'Jan', 1000),
       ('Product A', 'North', 'Feb', 2000),
       ('Product A', 'South', 'Jan', 3000),
       ('Product A', 'South', 'Feb', 4000),
       ('Product B', 'North', 'Jan', 5000),
       ('Product B', 'North', 'Feb', 6000),
       ('Product B', 'South', 'Jan', 7000),
       ('Product B', 'South', 'Feb', 8000);
```

Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Month2) 
                   FROM Sales
                   group by Month2
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                   ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                  ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT ProductName, Region, ' + @cols + ', 
                    SUM(Amount2) AS Total, 
                    SUM(SUM(Amount2)) OVER (PARTITION BY Region) AS RegionTotal,
                    SUM(SUM(Amount2)) OVER () AS GrandTotal
             FROM (
                SELECT ProductName, Region, Month2, Amount2
                FROM Sales
             ) AS s
             PIVOT (
                SUM(Amount2)
                FOR Month2 IN (' + @cols + ')
             ) AS p
             GROUP BY ProductName, Region, ' + @cols + ' WITH ROLLUP';


execute sp_executesql @query;
```

> Invalid column name 'Amount2'.

fiddle demo https://dbfiddle.uk/nHnDjMSd

Expected results:

```
ProductName  Region Jan    Feb   Total
Product A    North  1000   2000  3000
Product A    South  3000   4000  7000
Product B    North  5000   6000  11000
Product B    South  7000   8000  15000
Total               16000  20000  36000
```

Comment: `Amount2` no longer exists after it has been used in a pivot. You would need to reference it by the pivoted column names instead.

Comment: At times like this, you might find that conditional aggregation is a better option to the restrictive `PIVOT` operator.

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add row/column/grant totals in dynamic pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75715419/add-row-column-grant-totals-in-dynamic-pivot-table)

Comment: @PatrickHurst Thanks for your feedback. How to reference it by the pivoted column names?

Comment: @Larnu Since there are unknown number of columns, I have to use dynamic pivot.  Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: @siggemannen Thanks. that works for non-numerical variables.  I don't know why it does not work in this case.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: UNION ALL / VALUES demands that a column have same datatype in all "union rows". If you mix numbers / strings, you need to CAST your numbers to NVARCHAR so they will be the same

Comment: @ben you need to call them by the names defined in the pivot. We can't see them as you're using dynamic sql to provide them. If they are invalid names you'll need to escape them with braces: `[1col]`

Comment: If you post the fixed code, i'm sure it will be easy to see what the problem is

Comment: @Charlieface I added the expected results.  Thanks.

Comment: *" Do you have any better ideas?"* Yes, don't (dynamically) pivot your data in the SQL layer, do it in the presentation layer. Otherwise conditional aggregation is the "best"™ idea in my opinion; you can make it dynamic just like pivot if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you are far better off doing a manual pivot using `GROUP BY` and conditional `SUM(CASE`.

In your case, you also want a partial rollup. Do not use the deprecated `WITH ROLLUP` syntax. Either use `ROLLUP(columns)` or better use `GROUPING SETS`.

Furthermore, because your months are in text (bad idea) you need to sort them using `ORDER BY CONVERT...`

```sql
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = (
  SELECT '
  SUM(CASE WHEN Month2 = ' + QUOTENAME(Month2, '''') + ' THEN Amount2 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Month2) + ','
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY
    Month2
  ORDER BY CONVERT(date, Month2 + ' 01 2001', 100)
  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');

SET @query = '
SELECT
  ISNULL(ProductName, ''Total'') AS ProductName,
  Region,' + @cols + '
  SUM(Amount2) AS Total
FROM Sales
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (Region, ProductName),
  ()
);
';

PRINT @query;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/1twesJzr)

You can also add extra grouping sets, for example `(Region)`